# What is the equivalent of this way of looping over an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and excuse me if this seems very basic, but I can't figure out how to do a simple for-in loop in react that renders out a list of html elements. I figured out how to do it with `Array.map`, but `.map` is native only to Arrays, not objects. I need to go through some weird hoops to get what I need done. I end up with this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FormSelect extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="{this.props.name}">{this.props.label}</label>
        <select name="{this.props.name}" className="form-control"
                required="{this.props.required}">
          { Object.keys(this.props.options).map(function(option){
            return <option>{option}</option>
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I would love to be able to do it with a simple for-in loop. How would you rewrite this using a for-in loop?

What is the recommended way of looping over an object like this in React?

Comment: For this and/or future questions, we may be able to help you better if you provide a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing it is fine, other than that you're not using the *value* of the options for anything, just their names.

The alternative would be to make `this.props.options` an array, so you could skip the `Object.keys` part.

But if it's an object, and you want to loop its (own enumerable) properties, `Object.keys(...).map(...)` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the recommended way of looping over an object like this in React?

What you have is fine. You can use a `for...in` loop as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FormSelect extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const options = [];
    for (const option in this.props.options) {
      options.push(<option>{option}</option>);
    }

    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="{this.props.name}">{this.props.label}</label>
        <select name="{this.props.name}" className="form-control"
                required="{this.props.required}">
          {options}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `for...in` and `Object.keys` return a different set of properties though.

---

JSX syntax is nothing but function calls. E.g. `<div id="foo">bar</div>` becomes `React.createElement('div', {id: 'foo'}, 'bar')`. With this out if the way, everything else is just plain JavaScript.